# Does the image stabilizer on Canon lenses decrease the overall image quality?

Tags: lens, image-stabilization

When I'm shooting hand-held during the day, when the light is strong enough for the camera to shoot at 1/2000 and slower (therefore the image stabilizer should be useless, right?), should I disable the IS on my lens, or should I leave it enabled anyway? What about cases when using a tripod, for example?

I know that IS consumes the battery a little more, but let's ignore this fact. Let's talk about the produced image quality.

Comment: The title does not describe the question well. I thought you meant to compare IS vs non-IS lenses.

Comment: @ysap: The title describes the question just fine. The only way you could have arrived at the conclusion that this is an IS vs. non-IS lens question is because *you* made the assumption that it was...

Comment: @Jay - Image Stabilizer is there, whether activated or not. So, asking if Image Stabilizer reduces quality on a lens with IS is meaningless. The question should have been something like "Does activating IS reduce IQ on fast shutter speeds?". Just my 2 cents.

Comment: ysap why don't you just edit the title yourself? you have enough reputation to do it, nobody will be mad ;)

Comment: Question is clear as a bell to me. +1

Comment: @RiMMER - I'd rarely edit someone's post. I prefer expressing my opinion and let the OP make the decision whether to accept it or not (here's an example for this principle: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9869/terminal-velocity/9871#9871). Two other commenters here claim the question is clear enough, so who am I to argue ;-)

Comment: @RiMMER - other than that, I just leave *that* pleasure to mattdm ;-)

Comment: I've notices dome weird patters in the bokeh of sunlight reflections off water in the background of images where I am using IS, but that's the only thing time I have noticed IS having an effect.

Comment: Clear enough to me too, but I had to get rid of the extraneous "s". :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It is documented that stabilization should be disabled when shooting from a tripod.** This is because the stabilization system me try to compensate for inexistent movement and create a feedback loop. In this case you would lose image quality.

**Sometimes it is done for you:**

- Some modern high-end lenses supposedly detect when mounted on a tripod and turn off stabilization automatically. *Disclaimer: I own no such lens, so I do not know how well it works.*
- Pentax DSLRs automatically disable stabilization, which is provided by the body, when a self-timer or remote is used.

For high shutter-speeds, I am not entirely sure. There were anecdotal evidence that some lens-based stabilization system had trouble at shutter-speeds faster than 1/1000s and caused increased blur unless disabled. I have never seen it happen but I haven't tried every combination of lens and shutter-speed :)